# Regex in JavaScript to test for text in a URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I came up with this using different bits and pieces of working code from here but I cant understand why this does not work and what would it take to make it work...

Basically this is supposed to use some regext  expression to test for pages "page1.aspx" and "page2.aspx" (case can be upper and lower case). If it meets that criteria, it should also make sure that the url does not contain "text1" and "text2". Here is what I have...

```
<script> 

if (/page1\.aspx||page2\.aspx/i.test(self.location.href)) {
    if (!/text1||text2/i.test(self.location.href)) {
            var warnMessage = true;

            window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
                if (!warnMessage) {
                    return;
            }
                else {
                    return "Please save first.";
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input:submit, .buttons').click(function () {
                    warnMessage = false;
                });
            });
    } 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: really you don't want to validate the URL?

Comment: You have `||`. Did you mean `|`?

Comment: Validate? Note sure about that.

Ahh, I will try it with 1 "|". The reason why I have it with two "||" is because it was working in my previous example (but probably not the right way to do it in regex)...

if (document.location.href.indexOf('page1.aspx') > -1 || document.location.href.indexOf('page2.aspx') > -1)

Comment: Woaa! The double || was the killer for me, all fixed! Thanks!